# Resolve conflict between JUnit Vintage and custom JUnit engine

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I am working on a (heavily customized) test framework that is supposed to be compatible with both JUnit 4 and JUnit 5.

Therefore, I have a custom JUnit 4 runner **and** a custom JUnit 5 engine, both capable of discovering test cases, based on a custom annotation on the test class / method.

Everything works perfectly fine, if the end user runs their test using JUnit 4 or using JUnit 5 with **only** the custom engine included.

However, problems arise when the user includes JUnit Vintage *in addition* to the custom engine. Since the tests are eligible for detection by both engines, they are being run twice.

Assuming I cannot change the current approach (custom test runner + custom JUnit 5 engine), what would be the easiest way to solve this problem?

I guess I'm looking for sth along the lines of:

```
public final class CustomTestEngine extends HierarchicalTestEngine<CustomEngineExecutionContext> {


    @Override
    public TestDescriptor discover(EngineDiscoveryRequest discoveryRequest, UniqueId uniqueId) {
        if (someJUnitApi.getDetectedEngines().contains(JUnitVintageEngine.class)) {
            // skip tests contained in JUnit 4 test classes - JUnit Vintage will take care of them 
        }
    }
}
```

Where `someJUnitApi.getDetectedEngines()` needs to cover all the bases: engine auto-detection enabled/disabled, applied engine filters, additional test engines added to the launcher etc.

(I know I could just apply the `if` part unconditionally, esentially forcing the user to use Vintage if they want their `@RunWith` - annotated tests to run at all, but I am only willing to consider that option as a measure of last resort)

Comment: You could exclude vintage engine in your Gradle or Maven setup. Apart from that there‘s no API to list detected engines, but if you want you can check in your code which implementations of TestEngine have been registered through Java‘s Service Loader.

Comment: @johanneslink 'you can check in your code which implementations of TestEngine have been registered through Java‘s Service Loader' - that doesn't cover the `Launcher.autodetectTestEngines = false` scenario. Also, the problem is this is not *my* Gradle/Maven setup we're talking about, this is the *end user's*. I want to avoid forcing the end user to exclude Vintage, because they might be using it for other tests in their project